# Check hyperlink fields on MS-Access if broken without click the links

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

Is there a way to check an Access Table with many hyperlinks fields and contains hundreds of records if any of these hyperlinks are not working without clicking each link?
**Note: All hyperlinks are referring to files & folders.**

[image]

[Access Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LRvkzPcdJNDW1eSdYVfL5cxMMsGfTjm1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: By hyperlink fields, you mean Access Hyperlink type field? It would be difficult, though not impossible, to save non-valid link in Hyperlink field. What do you mean by 'working' - that the referenced file or folder exists?

Comment: Yes, the purpose is to check if the file/folder does not exist without clicking on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my function `DownloadFile` found at [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl) in an expression in a query, as the function returns 0 (zero) if the URL is live.

```
IsBroken: CBool(DownloadFile(Nz([YourUrlField]), "C:\Test\Delete.tmp"))
```

When done, delete `C:\Test\Delete.tmp`.

Comment: I tried it, but it is not helpful in my case, I want to check if the existing hyperlink to a local file/folder is working "when I clicked on the link the file/folder is opening" but without clicking on the 1000s of hyperlinks.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this code will do. Run the query (one click) and it will list all links as working or not.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong parameters! I created a test query and used the hyperlink filed as the first parameter and the file name with the full path as a second parameter. but the result was -1 for nonblank records (even link to a missed file) or #error for blank fields.

Comment: If the URL can be blank (_Null_) use `Nz` as shown. The second parameter should be a fixed path having a folder that exists.

Comment: I want to check if the linked folder/file moved/deleted/renamed so, the second parameter maybe doesn't exist.

Comment: I added a sample access DB with your function in a query.

Comment: The second parameter is a _fixed_ temp file that will keep being overwritten. It is not related to the link, and the folder (`C:\Test` or anything else) must exist.

Comment: Finally, it works but after replacing the default hyperlink value from "C:\Test\File1.txt#C:\Test\File1.txt#" to "C:\Test\File1.txt" and adding a fixed tmep. file as the second parameter. thanks @Gustav - I replaced the sample file

Comment: I noticed that with hyperlinks to folders results -1 not 0